# Is there a way to search for answers with specific tags

Tags: tags, asking-questions, support

Is there a way to search where it will search under specific tags.  I have a question and it relates to I would think a specific tag.

Specifically:

I want to search for answers to the following question:

```
The import android.os.ServiceManager cannot be resolved
```

in the tag `android-source`

Perhaps it's in the way the question is crafted, but it's not obvious to me how to do this.

Please advise.  :^)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can put a tag name in brackets from the search page to filter by tag, i.e.:

> [android-source] ServiceManager "cannot be resolved"

Comment: Might be helpful to add.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/9DlZ8.png